# How can I use a selected value from a look up data frame for further use (e.g., data queries and graphics) in a shiny app?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, shiny

In a shiny app, I want to translate a selected input value from column `lab` in data frame `look` to get the corresponding value from column `var` (the input values for selection are rendered from the data frame `look`). My goal is to use this translated value for further use to create, for instance, graphics. The code below works and the shiny app behaves as expected. However, the console gives the warning:

```
Warning: Error in <Anonymous>: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
ℹ Input `..1` is `var == choice()`.
x Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
ℹ Input `..1` is `lab == input$cat`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 3 or 1, not size 0.
  225: <Anonymous>
```

I suspect that the object/function `choice()`, which is passed to the function `filter()`, does not contain just a single value – at least not in a format that is expected. How can I resolve this issue, that is, how can I extract a "clean" value from a data frame and pass it onwards for further use?

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Data
data <- data.frame(
  var = c("a",  "a",  "a",  "b",  "b",  "b",  "c",  "c",  "c"),
  qtr = c(1,    2,    3,    1,    2,    3,    1,    2,    3),
  avg = c(1.1,  2.1,  3.1,  0.1,  1.1,  2.1, -2.1, -1.1,  0.1),
  lci = c(0.1,  1.1,  2.1, -1.1,  0.1,  1.1, -3.1, -2.1, -1.1),
  uci = c(2.1,  3.1,  4.1,  1.1,  2.1,  3.1, -1.1,  0.1,  1.1)
)

# Lookup
look <- data.frame(
  var = c("a", "b", "c"),
  lab = c("Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3")
)

# User Interface
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarPanel(
    
    uiOutput("select")
    
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    
   plotOutput(outputId = "plot")
   
    )
  )

# Server Function
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$select <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      inputId = "cat",
      label = "Category",
      choices = unique(look$lab)
    )
  })
  
  choice <- reactive({
    look %>% 
      dplyr::filter(lab == input$cat) %>% 
      dplyr::select(var) %>% 
      .[, 1] %>%
      as.vector()
    })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    data %>%
      dplyr::filter(var == choice()) %>%
      # dplyr::filter(var == "a") %>% 
      ggplot2::ggplot(aes(y = avg, x = qtr)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lci, ymax = uci), width = .1) +
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "black", size = .5)
  })
  
}

# App

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the issue is that when your app starts `input$cat` is `NULL`. To fix that add a `req(input$cat)` to your `reactive` and/or use `%in%` to filter your data, i.e. do `filter(lab %in% input$cat)`.

Additionally note, that I replaced `dplyr::select(var) %>% .[, 1] %>% as.vector()` by `dplyr::pull(var)`.

```r
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("select")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "choice"),
    plotOutput(outputId = "plot")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$select <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      inputId = "cat",
      label = "Category",
      choices = unique(look$lab)
    )
  })

  choice <- reactive({
    req(input$cat)
    
    look %>%
      dplyr::filter(lab == input$cat) %>%
      dplyr::pull(var)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({    
    data %>%
      dplyr::filter(var == choice()) %>%
      ggplot2::ggplot(aes(y = avg, x = qtr)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lci, ymax = uci), width = .1) +
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "black", size = .5)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5228
#> Warning: Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Running your code still gives the warning on my machine. However, adding `req(input$cat)` to the `output$plot` definition makes the warning go away. Based on your reply, another idea came to mind: adding a "start button logic" to the app.

Comment: interesting. Just checked again. And don't get a warning or error. But yes. Using an `actionButton` is also an option to "slow down" the reactive graph and preventing such errors.

Comment: I marked your answer as accepted solution. The different app behavior might has somehing to do with my package version since I have to work with relatively old package versions on my machine.